# __weak self in blocks

Tags: objective-c

I have __weak reference to self. Do I need __weak reference for controller2 and controller 3 which are also referenced in the competition block ?

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

id controller1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller1"];

id controller2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller2"];

id controller3 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller3"];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:^{

    [(UINavigationController *)weakSelf.parentViewController setViewControllers:@[controller2, controller3] animated:NO];

}];
```

**EDIT** what about the following code?  Does the block in the following code require a weak reference to self?

```
typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) MyCustomBlock customBlock;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.customBlock = ^{
        [(UINavigationController *)weakSelf.parentViewController setViewControllers:@[controller2, controller3] animated:NO];
    };
    [self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:self.customBlock];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This would present a view controller, then immediately change the view controllers shown by the navigation controller (which you should get to via `self.navigationController`, BTW)

Comment: Forget about the app logic.Do I need to add lines : __weak typeof(controller1) weakController1 = controller1; __weak typeof(controller2) weakController2 = controller2 ?

Comment: If you needed them, the compiler would tell you so. You usually need them only when you reference self or instance variables (which implicitly references self).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its harmless (in this case) to declare and use `weak` copies, but **none** of the block's references need to be `weak`.

The question is a symptom of a common misunderstanding: All objects to which a block refers are maintained as strong references (retained) by the block.  If any those objects in turn keep a strong reference to the block, then you have a retain cycle.

Just like it sounds, a retain cycle is when objects strongly refer to each other, either directly:

```
block ---> objectA ---> block  ("--->" means retains)
```

... or indirectly:

```
block ---> objectA ---> objectB ---> block
```

Retain cycles are bad because the system won't free objects that are retained by other objects.  So when we try to free the block, we can't because (in the direct case) it's retained by objectA, and we can't free objectA because it's retained by the block.

The simple fix is to declare a `weak` copy of the pointer, telling the block in essence "Don't retain this object.  I promise it will outlive the block".

Looking at the OP code, the block passed to `presentViewController` isn't retained at all.  It's held long enough to do the presentation, invoked when the animation is complete and then discarded.  Since none of the objects referred to by the block retain a copy of that block, there's no risk for a retain cycle, and no need for any `weak` references at all.

```
// initialize controller1, 2, 3

// no need for this
//__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:^{
    // perfectly safe...
    [(UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController setViewControllers:@[controller2, controller3] animated:NO];
}];
```

**EDIT** 
Regarding the additional code in the edit:  Yes, in that case, since you retain the block and the block refers to self, a weak copy must be used in order to avoid the retain cycle.

Comment: Is that a good example ? typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) MyCustomBlock customBlock;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    
    self.customBlock = ^{
    
        [weakSelf.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
        [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        
    };

Comment: @adobels, sorry, I don't understand the comment, which looks like an example where you would want a weak reference.  But its different from the code in the OP.

Comment: Check this one typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) MyCustomBlock customBlock;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    
    self.customBlock = ^{
    
     [(UINavigationController *)weakSelf.parentViewController setViewControllers:@[controller2, controller3] animated:NO];
  
    };
    
    [self presentViewController:controller1 animated:YES completion:self.customBlock];
    
}

Comment: @adobels - Its customary to ask such things in the question.  I added your additional question as an edit to the question and answered as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @danh I don't clearly see why there is no retain cycle in the `[self presentView...]` example. Is it because the block is not a property of `self`, so it is still in the stack and gets released after the execution of the method? How can you know if a block isn't a property in a subclass?

Comment: @PabloA., yes.  In the first example, the block is not being retained by anything.  You're right in pointing out that it could be a property of the *superclass* "self" (not subclass... it is not returned).  There, I think, it's non-retention is implied because its positioned as an animation completion block.  Imagine if the SDK retained all of those!  Its a good note for if you're writing a library for someone else: do your best not to retain blocks they pass you.

Comment: Good clarification @danh. And yeah, I meant superclass, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just as addition to @danh's response, when you declare a block property do it as copy, since blocks start on the stack, and they need to be moved to the heap in order to keep a strong reference to them.

```
typedef void(^MyCustomBlock)(void);

@property (nonatomic, copy) MyCustomBlock customBlock;
```